# -webkit-input-placeholder

Tags: html, css, placeholder

В браузере где найти стили -webkit-input-placeholder? Просто никак не пойму , где они перекрываются... В остальных браузерах отображается нормально.

Comment: "В браузере где найти" - в каком?

Comment: а что у вас не получается ?

Comment: в хроме, подсказали, надо , оказывается после каждого селектора ставить `-webkit-input-placeholder`.

Comment: Я не понял ни вопроса, ни ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо использовать следующий селектор для применения стиля к placeholder какого-либо input'a:
    `input[placeholder] { тут ваш набор стилей; }`    
Если inputов несколько то можете изменять стиль placeholder через классы:
    
`.class-name[placeholder] { /* тут ваш набор стилей */}`